# AWS Cloud formation does not copy the data to the newly created stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

In AWS cloud formation, i use the cloud former tool. I can use that tool to create a cloud formation template from existing resources. And then use the template to create a stack. I tested with that tool.  It can work, (as in it can create instances with same memory size, with same volume size, same VPC settings, and auto start the instances). But there is no files in the volume.

Do i have to create a snapshot of the existing volume, create a new volume from the snapshot, attach it to the newly created instance, and copy the files manually ?

Or is there any better way ?

Answer (score 1):

> Do i have to create a snapshot of the existing volume, create a new volume from the snapshot, attach it to the newly created instance, and copy the files manually ?

Cloudformation is **provisioning resources**, but is not responsible for provisioning the **contents** of those resources - that you have to do yourself.

You can leverage the [EC2 Userdata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html#user-data-shell-scripts) to manually pull files from S3 or other repos as the instance boots.

> Or is there any better way ?

If you want to share data between applications, **EFS** is always an option.  In your case, though, using Userdata might be effective.

Comment: I read the EC2 Userdata page, i do not see there is command to copy the user data from existing EC2 to newly created EC2. My user data refers to installed programs, the mysql data, etc.

Comment: Is it possible to modify the template , and make it point to the AMI that i created from existing images? So that user data is copied over to new EC2 during cloud formation stack creation process?

Comment: If my EBS snapshot was from a root EBS volume, can i?

Mount the volume as the root volume of a compatible EC2 instance,
Start the EC2 instance with the new root volume.

Comment: @styling if you create an AMI from your existing EC2, you can specify that AMI as the new EC2 AMI.   You cannot mount the same EBS volume to more than one EC2 at once, but you can snapshot it and create a new volume from the snapshot.

Comment: so can i mount the new volume from the snapshot, to the newly created ec2 instance, as root volume ? Bearing in mind, the newly created ec2 instance from cloud formation, has a root volume already.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to launch new EC2 instances with software automatically loaded, there are basically two choices:

- Use a pre-configured AMI, or
- Use a startup script to load the software

**Pre-configured AMI**

An Amazon Machine Image (AMI) is a copy of a disk. When a new EC2 instance is launched, an AMI is selected and the boot disk (and optionally other disks) are automatically pre-loaded with the contents of the AMI.

A common practice is to boot an EC2 instance and configure it as desired. Then, create an AMI. Thereafter, when a new EC2 instance is required for the application, launch it using the pre-built AMI.

There are also tools available to automate the building of an AMI, such as [Netflix Aminator](https://github.com/Netflix/aminator) and [Packer](https://www.packer.io/).

**Benefits:** New machine boots quickly, fully-configured.

**Issues:** Need to create a new AMI whenever you update your software.

**Use a startup script to load the software**

When an Amazon EC2 instance is launched from a standard Amazon-provided AMI (eg Amazon Linux, Microsoft Windows), software on the AMI automatically looks at the **User Data** passed to an EC2 instance. If the User Data contains a [startup script](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html), the script will be executed -- but only the first time that an instance is launched. This is an excellent way to install software on the instance.

You are responsible for writing the script. The script should install whatever tools, software and data you want on the instance.

**Benefits:** Updating your software? Just launch a new instance and the script will install the latest version of your software (assuming you have written the script to always point to the latest version).

**Issues:** It takes longer to launch the new instance, since the software is being installed.

Comment: I can create snapshot from existing ec2 instance. Can i mount the new volume from the snapshot, to the newly created ec2 instance, as root volume ? Bearing in mind, the newly created ec2 instance from cloud formation, has a root volume already. –

Comment: An AMI is exactly the same thing as a Snapshot, but it can be used as a root volume (and can contain multiple volumes). So, create an AMI instead of a Snapshot (or an AMI *from* the snapshot), select it when you start the machine and your files will be there when the machine starts up.

Comment: *select it when you start the machine*, can we select AMI when we start the ec2 instance?

Comment: Yes. If you launch an instance via the console, you select an AMI on the very first screen. Normally you would use an Amazon-provided AMI, but you can instead select **MyAMIs** to choose an AMI you created previously. If you launch the instance via an API call, the AMI is one of the specified parameters.

Comment: I am using cloud formation tool. It does not have option to choose my customised AMI.

Comment: When launching an instance from CloudFormation, you are required to specify an AMI in the `ImageId` field. Simply use the ID of your own AMI in that field.

Comment: Thank you.  I will do that.